# Codeigniter breadcrumb same lading page design

Tags: php, codeigniter, breadcrumbs

Im totally new to Code-Igniter. I manage to get the breadcrumb library to work but i do not know on how to get it working for the same end pages with different path. 
Example:

1) Home -> Cute Animal -> Cat
2) Home -> Lovely Pet -> Cat
3) Home -> People -> Type of People -> Cat

I used this codeigniter library 
https://github.com/aburd/Codeigniter-breadcrumbs

Example of use

```
// load Breadcrumbs<br>
$this->load->library('breadcrumbs');

// add breadcrumbs (add breadcrumb to end)<br>
$this->breadcrumbs->push('Section', '/section',);

// add breadcrumb with Base Site URL i use it on the controller of the particular view(cat.php)<br>
$this->breadcrumbs->push('Page', '/section/page', true);

// unshift crumb (add breadcrumb to front)<br>
$this->breadcrumbs->unshift('Home', '/');

// unshift crumb with Base Site URL<br>
$this->breadcrumbs->unshift('Home', '/', true);

// output i put it on the view page(cat_view)<br>
$this->breadcrumbs->show();
```

Comment: show output or error in the output @toy

Comment: @saurabhkamble sorry for the misunderstand question. I do not know how to implement the function on the controller to show different breadcrumb path in same ending page. The view page as example lovely pet, type of people and cute animal will lead to same cat view page when they click on the button.